# How to test only relevant items and remove popular items from test whit Crossfold in Lenskit 3.0-M2

Tags: lenskit

How can I configure the crossfold task to generate test sets only with relevant items.  That is, with rating values higher than the average rating of the user and do not consider the popular items?

Is it posible with lenskit-3.0?

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly possible - the crossfolder does not take into account rating values.

A patch that added such capabilities would be welcome; you can also directly emit train/test sets yourself in Python or R.

Comment: Hi Micheal!, thanks for your reply. Finally, I did with python. That is, I created the train/test sets with a python script’s and then changing the dataSet variable in the evaluate task.
But I am intrestly in add the patch that you say.  Maybe one possibility is add this capabilities into de method “holdout”, that is, send some variable to decide if the protocol to create train/test sets should consider the rating values. But I don’t know how to can begin add this code. Could you send me some information?

Comment: @CarlosRios Good to hear! Why don't you send me an e-mail, either personally or on the LensKit mailing list? I think that's a better forum for discussing development than StackOverflow.

Comment: Michael,  I send you an e-mail to your boisetate.edu mail.